# slds validation is not consistent on some are JavaScript others are ServerSide for the same logic

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, slds, fieldsets, required-field

### Problem

WE have different kinds of validation error messages appearing. We want to give a consistent user experience, but are struggling to do so. Any feedback would be helpful.

[image: serverside error]
[image: clientside error]

### Server Side ERROR HTML

```
 <apex:form id="theForm2">
                    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title slds-p-top_x-large">
                        <span>Add Bar Association History</span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                        <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!save}" value="Add" rerender="barAssociationsTableForm"
                            status="pageSavingStatus" />
                        <apex:actionStatus id="pageSavingStatus">
                            <apex:facet name="start">
                                <apex:outputPanel>
                                    <img src="/img/loading32.gif" width="25" height="25" />
                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Saving..." />
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:facet>
                        </apex:actionStatus>

                        <apex:outputPanel id="barAssociationsEditFields">
                            <apex:messages styleClass="errorMsg" />
                            <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
                                <div class="slds-form-element">
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-53">{!f.label}
                                        <apex:outputText value=" *" style="color:red;" rendered="{!f.Required}" />
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                                        <apex:outputPanel>
                                        <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input " value="{!barAssociationsForm[f.fieldPath]}" required="{!f.required}" />
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </apex:form>
```

### Client Side ERROR HTML

```
<apex:form>
                    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title slds-p-top_x-large">
                        Add Bar Admissions
                    </h2>
                    <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                        <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!save}" value="Add" rerender="theBarAdmissionsTableForm"
                            status="pageSavingStatus" />
                        <apex:actionStatus id="pageSavingStatus">
                            <apex:facet name="start">
                                <apex:outputPanel>
                                    <img src="/img/loading32.gif" width="25" height="25" />
                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Saving..." />
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:facet>
                        </apex:actionStatus>

                        <apex:outputPanel id="BarAdmissionsEditFields">
                            <apex:messages styleClass="errorMsg" />
                            <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
                                <div class="slds-form-element">
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-53">{!f.label}
                                        <apex:outputText value=" *" style="color:red;" rendered="{!f.Required}" />
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                                        <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input " value="{!barAdmissionsFormRecord[f.fieldPath]}" required="{!f.required}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </apex:form>
```

Comment: Can you share the html tags for each image ? The second  image looks like standard HTML5 error messasge.

Comment: Just added. THe more important thing is just understanding why the client side is firing. It just odd because they are both using SLDS for their styling.

Comment: But which tag loads the second image? I see VF page is loaded by the first `server-side-html`

Comment: As Nagendra said, it's your browser displaying the second message.  Try it in a different browser and it will look different.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I still am not clear on the "why". functionally speaking,  it's not a big deal at this point, but we trying to get the ux consistent and don't have a path forward.

Comment: Just tested in Edge. There is no difference in functionality. Same errors and styles.